# Why socket.io cannot connect to socket.io server for chat

Tags: android, android-studio, socket.io, serversocket

After cloning this repository, https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat I thought it should work without modifying anything and I can be able to login to chat with socket.io but after installing the app on my device it displays this error
(Failed to connect)
and I cannot to join with my nick name , anyone know what I must change in the code for the app to work correctly ?

url for connect socket is https://socket-io-chat.now.sh

Comment: have you tried creating an issue on the github repository? also please paste the relevant socket connection code.

Comment: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/issues